# Listbox selected items search with trackbar keyword or Range slider update on save

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, trackbar

Language: C#

IDE: Visual Studio 2013

Question: How do I set values to a trackbar in VS and then use these values as a variable for another process of my program.

Example: Game Difficulty - Player chooses difficulty on the track bar, then this integer value is then used as a speed variable for how fast a ball moves.

Comment: Simply use  the [`Value` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.value(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, which property sets the actual value of the 'ticks'?

Comment: I don't know what you mean, perhaps the [`TickFrequency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.trackbar.tickfrequency%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But please look at the documentation yourself :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yep, got it! It was tick frequency! Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tick frequency allows you to set a value for each of the ticks, so if your tick frequency starts at 10, then your first location would be 10, next 20 and so on.

To get this value from the `trackbar`, you have to use `'nameOfTrackbar'.Value`.